# Fixing invalid number of lines in tail by passing an integer into tail

Tags: linux, bash, centos

Running Centos8.

Here is my current (tiny) script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
x=$((($2-$1)+1))
head -n $2 $3 | tail -n -$x
```

As an example of an input:

```
sh script.sh 7 10 /etc/passwd
```

And what I am trying to get out is lines 7-10 from /etc/passwd.

It should be fairly simple, because just doing

```
head -n 7 /etc/passwd | tail -n -4
```

Returns those 4 lines perfectly fine.

However, using $x (to get the input from the second number, minus the first, plus 1), fails. Whenever I run this code I get this error:

```
tail: invalid number of lines: ‘4\r\r’
```

Which from my understanding means that the code is not accepting the $x input from the small math I did, and thinks that its 4 with two trailing spaces?

How would I go about fixing this issue, so that the four lines of /etc/password get listed?

Comment: Your script has dos line endings. Remove them with `dos2unix` or other utility. Esept for that, your script looks nice, but you need and should quote variable expansions, especially if they are filenames. Don't `$3`, do `"$3"`.

Comment: dos2unix fixed it! I was going from using IntelliJ on windows to a shared folder on Centos, so it must have been an error upon transfer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There's problem on line 3

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
x=$((($2-$1)+1))
head -n $1 $3 | tail -n -$x
```

That needs to say $1, not $2.

And the line endings are Mac, not Linux.